# Failed to process import candidates for configuration class in spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, spring-security-oauth2

Im trying to run my Spring MVC application but for some reason the `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter` cant be found.

Heres the code snippet:

```
package co.uk.zohaibkhan.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;


@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
    oauthServer.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory().withClient("my-trusted-client")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
        .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
        .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
        .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(5000)
        .secret("secret");
  }


  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    super.configure(endpoints);
  }
}
```

and the stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [co.uk.zohaibkhan.config.AuthorizationServerConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:616) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:296) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
...
```

Here is the dependencies from my `pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

```
 <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Could anyone lend a hand? the build works fine, i did have some issues resolving dependencies, but now everything looks good and i cant figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out!

So if you have a dependency that seems iffy, just delete it from maven and then go to the errors and autocorrect to find the maven dependencies, then use trial and error and find the correct one!

If no classes are showing up, then go on settings then to maven and there you should update your repositories

now my maven dependency that has changed looks like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```