# FileNotFoundException: class path resource ***/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have following dependencies:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth', name: 'spring-security-oauth2', version: '2.0.2.RELEASE'
```

and following sources(copiesd from http://www.baeldung.com/sso-spring-security-oauth2):

**main:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
public class AuthorizationServerApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthorizationServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**AuthServerConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("SampleClientId")
                .secret("secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .scopes("user_info")
                .autoApprove(true) ;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig:**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("john").password("123").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

**UserController:**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping("/user/me")
    public Principal user(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }
}
```

When I start application I see following:

```
2018-04-12 17:19:58.153  WARN 16828 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.my.sso.server.AuthServerConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2018-04-12 17:19:58.449 ERROR 16828 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.my.sso.server.AuthServerConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:645) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:194) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:293) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:202) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:170) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:316) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.my.sso.server.AuthorizationServerApplication.main(AuthorizationServerApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:51) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:88) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:75) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:731) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:947) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:330) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:359) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:265) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:635) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

What do I wrong?

**P.S.**
I found this classes in libraries but in another package:

```
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration
```

but spring tries to find it in the package:

```
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341277/failed-to-process-import-candidates-for-configuration-class-in-spring

Comment: It is possible that your configuration mixed SpringSecurity 4 and 5 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12456)

Comment: Changing the library name from "configurers" to "configuration" did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Probably some of your other dependencies depends on Spring Security 4 (where this class was in different package than in Spring Security 5).

I had the same problem. In my case it was activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic (6.0.0).

Comment: Did upgrade activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic to 6.0.0 solved or caused your problem?

Comment: It was a cause for an error. I wanted to upgrade project to Spring Boot 2. Then it appears that Activity 6 do not support Spring Boot 2. We have to wait with an upgrade (still we do) to Activity 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this dependency to your `pom.xml` file

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
     <version>4.2.12.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must have the same version .if you have 2.2.5 version for spring you must have 2.2.5 for spring security.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue with old version of activiti. Changing pom.xml dependency as below worked for me with Spring Security 5

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0.M6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work in my case.